# Include all records in between two dates

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with the columns `ID`, `start_time`, and `end_time`.
I would like to extract **all** the records that are active during a date range.

```
  ID | start_time |  end_time  
 ----|------------|------------ 
   1 | 2019-07-22 | 2019-07-25 
   2 | 2019-07-20 | 2019-07-25 
   3 | 2019-07-20 | 2019-07-21 
   4 | 2019-07-20 | 2019-07-25 
   5 | 2019-07-22 | 2019-07-22 
   6 | 2019-07-25 | 2019-07-25 
   7 | 2019-07-26 | 2019-07-27
```

#### Example Query parameters

- start: 2019-07-22
- end: 2019-07-25

Expected results (5 rows):

```
 ID | start_time |  end_time 
----|------------|------------
  1 | 2019-07-22 | 2019-07-25
  2 | 2019-07-20 | 2019-07-25
  4 | 2019-07-20 | 2019-07-25
  5 | 2019-07-22 | 2019-07-22
  6 | 2019-07-25 | 2019-07-25
```

<sup>*the row containing ID 7 is omitted, because it is not active in the specified date range*</sup>

I want to include the records with `start_time` 2019-07-20 because they are actually active on July 22.

If I use the following:

```
where start_time >= '2019-07-22' and end_time <= '2019-07-25'
```

...then I am excluding the records starting on July 20.

How can I include those records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're trying to find all active/valid records in a time frame, and you are using intervals, then you must use the following criteria:

1. End date was on/after the start of the window
2. Start date was on/before the start of the window

This is working on the assumption that a record is still effective as of the end date, as indicated in your example.

So your query becomes:

```
SELECT
  Id
 ,start_time
 ,end_time
FROM
  <your table>
WHERE
  start_time <= '2019-07-25'
    AND end_time >= '2019-07-22'
```

A simple truth table helps verify:

```
Id  | Start_Time  | End_Time    | Start <= 2019-07-25 | End >= 2019-07-22
1   | 2019-07-22  | 2019-07-25  | Y                   | Y
2   | 2019-07-20  | 2019-07-25  | Y                   | Y
3   | 2019-07-20  | 2019-07-21  | Y                   | N
4   | 2019-07-20  | 2019-07-25  | Y                   | Y
5   | 2019-07-22  | 2019-07-22  | Y                   | Y
6   | 2019-07-25  | 2019-07-25  | Y                   | Y
7   | 2019-07-26  | 2019-07-27  | N                   | Y
```

Other notes:
Those are dates, not times.  Column should be Start_Date/End_Date or Start_Datetime/End_Datetime if you are include hours/minutes/seconds (you can abbreviate with Dt/Dtm if you wish).

From comment:

> I assume that if I want to filter only for the startdate, I can do
> WHERE end_time >= '2019-07-22 00:00:00' But I am not sure about query
> only for the enddate. What is the correct condition? WHERE start_time
> <= '2019-07-25 23:59:59' OR WHERE '2019-07-25 00:00:00' BETWEEN
> start_time AND end_time

So here we need to be careful with what question is actually be asked, and what answer the query is providing.

The statement `WHERE end_time >= '2019-07-22 00:00:00'` is the same as saying: any records that end OR start on/after `2019-07-22 00:00:00`.

The inverse of that statement would be any records that start AND end before `2019-07-22 00:00:00`, which is `WHERE end_time < '2019-07-22 00:00:00'`.

So if your question is actually "Which records end or start **on/before** `2019-07-22 00:00:00` the condition is `WHERE start_time <= 2019-07-22 00:00:00`

Comment: Hi, yes you're absolutely right: 5 rows, not 6, my fault! Thanks for your time.